# redux-observable 2.0.0 - replacing action$.ofType() with pipeable operator

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

Now that in version 2.0.0 `action$.ofType()` has been removed in favor of a pipeable operator how can I achieve the following

```
        return obs.pipe(
          takeUntil(ofType(actionCreator.cancel.TYPE)),
          map(payload => actionCreator.success(payload, meta)),
          catchError(error => of(actionCreator.failure(error, meta))),
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little investigation, I found out the following works

```
        return obs.pipe(
          takeUntil(action$.pipe(ofType(actionCreator.cancel.TYPE))),
          map(payload => actionCreator.success(payload, meta)),
          catchError(error => of(actionCreator.failure(error, meta))),
        )
```